# Raw text as argument to string in Python

Tags: python, string, function

I have a function:

```
def list_printer(name):
    frame = sys._getframe(1)
    print(name, '=', repr(eval(name, frame.f_globals, frame.f_locals)))
    return
```

and a list:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

When called it looks like this:

```
list_printer('my_list')
```

and outputs:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

The thing is, as you can see I must use a string as the argument, is there any way I could type in raw text and then convert it to a string inside the function so that I don't have to use quotes?

Comment: Er, if you want to pass the object itself, then what's the point of all that horrible frame/eval stuff? Why not just `print(my_list)`?

Comment: Test the class of the object (`isinstance()`) passed.  If a string then you can do all that stuff.  If not a string then just print it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, "raw text" isn't a term. I believe you're asking if you can pass a variable directly to a function that prints the variable's name and value.

This isn't possible because variable names are not directly tied to the values they represent - they're [pointers or references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28computer_science%29). That means that when you call `f(my_list)` the *value* `my_list` references is passed to `f()`, but not the name "my_list".

If your intent is to print a variable name along with its value you need to do some sort of reflection (which your `list_printer` method is doing) in order to inspect the current state of your program and identify the variable named `"my_list"`.

Of course since you have to specify the variable name as a string anyways, you might as well just define a simpler function that associates a text label with a variable, like so:

```
def print_value(name, value):
  print('%s = %s' % (name, value))
```

Which you could call like so:

```
print_value('my_list', my_list)
```

But you could also put more context in the `name` field, e.g.:

```
print_value('my_list, defined in my_module', my_list)
```

To further aid debugging. You might also like to look into the Python debugger [`pdb`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html), since you're basically manually recreating a debugger.